# Array.isArray says to be false

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, destructuring

I'm a new javascript learner, currently learning destructuring.
My question is in a snippet which I edited a bit. The console says it's an array, but I didn't think it was supposed to be?

1: How is this not an array?

```js
const heroes = [{
  lol: ['l', 'Iron Man']
}]

const [lol, dc] = heroes;
console.log(Array.isArray(lol));
```

2: How is this one an array?

```js
const heroes = {
  lol: ['l', 'Iron Man']
}

const {lol, dc} = heroes;
console.log(Array.isArray(lol));
```

Comment: You've switched it up on yourself.

Comment: @tadman yes but in both cases value of 'lol' is an array so shouldn't 'lol' be also an array ?

Comment: Just out all values to the console and it becomes clear ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first snippet, `heroes` is an array. The first element of the array is the object

```
{
 lol:['l', 'Iron Man' ]
}
```

The destructuring assignment sets `lol` to this element, and sets `dc` to `undefined` because there's no second element in the array. The above object is not an array, so `Array.isArray(lol)` is false.

```js
const heroes = [{
 lol:['l', 'Iron Man' ]
}]

const [element1, element2 ] = heroes;
console.log(element1);
```

In the second snippet, `heroes` is an object. The destructuring assignment sets `lol` to the value of the `lol` property in the object, which is `['l', 'Iron Man']`. It sets `dc` to the `dc` property; since this doesn't exist, it's set to `undefined. Since` lol`is set to an array,`Array.isArray(lol)` is true.

If you want to set `lol` to the array in the first snippet, you need another level of nesting.

```js
const heroes = [{
 lol:['l', 'Iron Man' ]
}]

const [{lol, dc}] = heroes;
console.log(Array.isArray(lol));
```

Comment: You have very good answer but i want to know one thing here, in the first snippet, which is counted as an array ? as i see 'lol's value is an array ' ['l', 'Iron Man' ]' so doesnt it make lol an array also ? or because we have curly braces around 'lol' like this ' {
 lol:['l', 'Iron Man' ]
}' those curly braces makes it an object ?

Comment: Yes, curly braces make it an object.

Comment: No it isn't, it's an object. I added a snippet with `console.log(lol)`, you can see the value.

Comment: You're confusing the `lol` variable with the `lol` property inside the object.

Comment: Like @Barmar said, the value of `lol` is indeed an Array, but `{ lol }` is different: it's an object with `lol` as a property, rather than the array itself.

Comment: @Barmar maybe i sound stupid here but isnt those two 'lol's connected to each other, with one 'lol' we have access to another ? ' const [lol, dc ] =[{
 lol:['l', 'Iron Man' ]
}]
console.log(lol); 

 '

Comment: No, they're not connected. When you destructure into an array, it just uses the position, the property name inside the object is irrelevant. I changed my example snippet to use a different variable to show you.

Comment: but in the second snipped we must have same name inside the object ? those are connected ?

Comment: Right. When you destructure an object, the variable name matches the property. But you can also write `const [{ lol: someVar}] = heroes`. That uses `lol` as the property name, `someVar` as the variable name. `{lol}` is short for `{lol: lol}` and uses the property name as the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

because the first example you are trying to destructure using `[]` which is used for destructure arrays, However {} are to be used to destructure an object

so in you case you should first destructure the array first using `[]` and then inside `{}` to destructure the object

```js
const heroes = [{
  lol:['l', 'Iron Man' ]
 }]
 
 const [{lol, dr}] = heroes;
 console.log(lol)
 console.log(Array.isArray(lol));
```

Answer (score 0):

in const [lol, dc ] = heroes lol is an object {lol:['l', 'Iron Man' ]}
in const {lol, dc } = heroes lol is an array ['l', 'Iron Man' ]